# How to respond to mentions using Twitter API

Tags: node.js, serverside-javascript, twitter-streaming-api

I have a twitter bot that is functional. It complements someone when they reply to me, which is when  @myTwitterHandle is the first thing in the tweet. The following code allows me to respond to them:

```
function tweetEvent(tweet) {

  // Who is this in reply to?
  var reply_to = tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name;
  // Who sent the tweet?
  var name = tweet.user.screen_name;
  // What is the text?
  var txt = tweet.text;

  // Ok, if this was in reply to me
  // Replace myTwitterHandle with your own twitter handle
  console.log(reply_to, name, txt);
  if (reply_to === 'myTwitterHandle') {

  ¦ // Get rid of the @ mention
  ¦ txt = txt.replace(/@selftwitterhandle/g, '');

  ¦ // Start a reply back to the sender
  ¦ var reply = "You mentioned me! @" + name + ' ' + 'You are super cool!';

  ¦ console.log(reply);
  ¦ // Post that tweet!
  ¦ T.post('statuses/update', { status: reply }, tweeted);
  }
}
```

I just want to send the exact same reply whenever anyone @mentions me somewhere in the body of their tweet.  I am using Node.js and the [twit api client](https://github.com/ttezel/twit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you may be referencing the tutorial found [here](https://github.com/shiffman/A2Z-F15/blob/gh-pages/week9/10_twitter_replier_bot/bot.js)

I believe this is what you may be looking for

> I just want to send the exact same reply whenever anyone `@mentions` me
>   somewhere in the body of their tweet.

This script achieves the desired result:

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['@myTwitterHandle'] });
stream.on('tweet', tweetEvent);

function tweetEvent(tweet) {

    // Who sent the tweet?
    var name = tweet.user.screen_name;
    // What is the text?
    // var txt = tweet.text;
    // the status update or tweet ID in which we will reply
    var nameID  = tweet.id_str;

     // Get rid of the @ mention
    // var txt = txt.replace(/@myTwitterHandle/g, "");

    // Start a reply back to the sender
    var reply = "You mentioned me! @" + name + ' ' + 'You are super cool!';
    var params             = {
                              status: reply,
                              in_reply_to_status_id: nameID
                             };

    T.post('statuses/update', params, function(err, data, response) {
      if (err !== undefined) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Tweeted: ' + params.status);
      }
    })
};
```

Comment: The reply is sent, but not notified to the user, nor appears in their tweet thread. See this issue: https://twittercommunity.com/t/automated-replies-are-not-being-notified-to-users-nor-in-reply-thread/79994

Comment: @SantoshKumar not sure if this helps but I am using the Twit package with the above code found here: https://github.com/ttezel/twit. Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39028879/5884189